# Check if image could be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to determine weather I can fetch an image from the server. The URL for the file server is generated. I decided to check the image's natural height. This code snipped works when I reload a page, but when I try to fetch the image for the first time, it does not work. Is this some problem with the timing or is this code snippet completely wrong?

```
<p id="buildingPh"></p>

<script>

    $("#buildingPh").html("<img id='gebaeudeBild' width='100%' src='[image/url]'></img>" );

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if (document.getElementById("gebaeudeBild").naturalHeight == 0) {
            $("#buildingPh").html("No image found.");
        }
    });

</script>
```

This is the entire script. I am using AEM so thre is no more code

Comment: So you're using some other code to get the image? Are you running this on `document.ready()` when all assets have been loaded?

You need to add more details.

Comment: Please provide more details / code. How are you getting the image? Is it via an async method?

Comment: You can check if something exists using `.length`.

E.g. `if ( $('#image').length ) {
  // ID does exist, do something
}`

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @lee2808 but I think Image `load` if more appropriate to handle image error event..

```
    $("#buildingPh").html("<img onerror='error()'  id='gebaeudeBild' width='100%' src='[image/url]'></img>" );

  function error() {
       $("#buildingPh").html("No image found.");    
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Jquery try wrapping the function in jquery's wrapper for document ready:

```
$(function () {

    if (document.getElementById("gebaeudeBild").naturalHeight == 0) {
        $("#buildingPh").html("No image found.");
    }
});
```

This is just a hunch as there is not much detail provided in the question. Seems to be an async issue here if it's not working when you fetch the image for the first time.

Comment: Isn't this a IIFE? jQuery uses `document.ready()` to run when the page is loaded.

Comment: @PaulRedmond: jQuery has several different ways to add a ready handler, see https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: This is actually shorthand https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/